# Getting mongoStat through mongoDB Java driver

Tags: java, monitoring, mongodb

Is there a way to get the results of the [mongostat](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongostat) utility such as no. of queries/sec, inserts/sec, etc. through java driver. 
One way I find out was to get the  serverstatus through the Mongo object as:

```
db.command("serverStatus")
```

and then get the total queries performed till now and then manipulate it to get queries per second.

Is there any other better way to get this information?

Comment: you asked this same question on the MongoDB mailing list a few days ago and were provided with answers : http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/a70bf2d7dbd2a13b/a5b42fe3e7991d32

Comment: @Brendan Thanks for your response. The method that was told on the mongoDb mailing list is the method that I have posted over here. I was trying to know if there is a direct method. Because if I'll use `db.command("serverStatus")` , I'll get the total no. of queries that have been performed on the server. Then I'll have to poll and subtract the previous result from the current result. I was just wondering if there was any utility implemented in the java driver which could return the final result straight away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Db.command("ServerStatus")` function to get the Server Status and you can keep polling