# MongoDB query database for time

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to query mongodb in such a way that I can retrieve the time?

I often do a check where I check the time the mongodb server is running on before putting data on. I need to know the time on the db server from the point of view of a client.

I'm using the C# .NET wrapper, but if there is a query that can do this on any platform that would be nice too. How would would I get the db time?

I know there are obviously other ways to do this, by synchronizing times. But I need to use this option so there can be no tampering with the local time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`db.hostInfo()` returns an object where `system.currentTime` is the current time on the server's host.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "from the point of view of a client".  But, this might help:

```
>> db.serverStatus()
```

returns a big object, which includes the time.  Apparently (haven't tested this), for the java driver you can get this with Db.command("serverStatus"), so I would imagine something similar works in C#.

References:

[Mongo docs for serverStatus](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/)

[An answered question about serverStatus in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310212/getting-mongostat-through-mongodb-java-driver)

Comment: I mean't the time on the server and not on the client side of the connection. This should do it